# Understanding C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

I have been reading "Jumping Into C++" by Alex Allain. I understood the first few chapters consisting on the basics, up through Functions. As soon as it started talking about passing variables to functions and continuing on to arrays, structures and enums I could not follow the book very easily. In fact only about 25% of the end chapter exercises can be completed without finding the answer from someone else.

My question is this:
Is there a better book on C++ or online reference that I could continue my self-education with? I just feel like it's not explained to me in a way that I can grasp. I don't know if this is because I just simply can't grasp it or if there's a different resource I could use that may change my outlook on it.

Any suggestions would be very helpful, thanks for any input!

Comment: We do have this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You want to learn C and you tagged the Q C++. First thing you need to understand is both are different languages.

Comment: @AlokSave I fixed the title, body consistently talks of C++

Comment: @chris The link to different books was great, I'll be using those too, thanks. I feel like I understand everything 100% until passing things. I just get lost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [*The C++ Programming Language*](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd.html), which is like the Bible™ for C++ programmers, at least, new incomers.

Comment: It's just that I doubt a *"new incomer"* can wrap its head around wth *"TC++PL"* could actually stand for.

Comment: I think start learning C++ with such a book is great because it exposes the good practices and discards the possibility to write error-prone code. Well it’s C++ I know, but that book is imho a good start. More complicated ones would be « Modern C++ », « Modern C++ Design » by Alexandrescu, for instance.

Comment: @skp Christian referred to the fact that the OP - or other non-experienced coders finding this page in the future - will not know what the abbreviation **`TC++PL`** meant... (By the way it's [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd.html))

Comment: @skp I think you didn't get my comment. I have no problem with *"TC++PL"* at all (well, for a beginner that doesn't get what passing a variable to a function means it's probably still way too magical, but that is a different problem). It's just that I don't think that *"new incomers"* will understand what the *phrase* *"TC++PL"* actually means (is it the name of a book?).